# Can I register receiver for Download Manager's Download Incomplete action in Android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I want to register receiver for Download manager's download incomplete action.
Actually I have a code where I am showing a loader while downloading a file and due to Insufficient Storage error.It ends up with Download incomplete notification in notification tray.
But As I have registered receiver for`DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` . But It never got called as Actual action is Download incomplete. So My loader is not getting dismissed.
My Question is how should I detect `INSUFFICIENT_SPACE_ERROR` , So I can dismiss the loader and display appropriate message to User?

Another Alternative I  have tried is -
I am calculating Available space on SD Card before downloading the file, But in that case too, On which threshold value I should write condition?

My Code -

```
BroadcastReceiver attachmentDownloadCompleteReceive = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                        DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                openDownloadedAttachment(context, downloadId);
            }
            else {
                // Loader Dismissed and Displayed appropriate Message to user.
            }
        }
    };
```

Can you please help me with this?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: can you share your Broadcast Reciever class?

Comment: Hey Rohit , Added my code for Receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/networking/android-download-manager-tutorial-download-file-using-download-manager-internet/) example. In this approach, your data status column will tell you the exact download status of the file.

Accordingly, hide the progress dialog and display the appropriate message.

Comment: I am Doing in the same way. Just the problem is that,the receiver was not getting called for that scenario.